# Настройка VNC клиента

Tags: сеть, администрирование

Хочу получить доступ к "малинке" через VNC. Там стоит (и работает) x11vnc. На десктопе, с которого хочу коннектится - Fedora 32 + TigerVNV клиент. Одно время всё работало нормально, но вдруг перестало. При запуске клиента вижу такую картину:

```
$ vncviewer

TigerVNC Viewer (64-разрядная версия) 1.10.1
Сборка от: 2020-04-19 00:00
© 1999-2019, TigerVNC Team и многие другие (см. README.rst)
Информация о TigerVNC на сайте https://www.tigervnc.org

Sun Jun 21 00:52:25 2020
 DecodeManager: Detected 8 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s)
 CConn:       Подключён к компьютеру 192.168.0.112,
              порт 5900
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 5.0
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: No matching security types
 CConn:       No matching security types
```

Т.е. клиент видит сервер, соединяется с ним, начинает попытку логина, но не может подобрать параметры секретности. Я уже все мыслимые комбинации перепробовал - никакого эффекта.

На малинке - всё по умолчанию, настроек вообще не касался.

Сейчас клиент настроен так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение вот тут:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176408

Проблема была в том, что после обновления VNC-сервера режимом шифорвания по умолчанию стало "Шифровать". А TigerVNC этого не понимает.

Я зашёл в настройки сервера на "малинке" и установил параметр "Шифрование" в значение "Нет". Проблема исчезла.